# Подскажите в чем дело в выводе

Tags: c++-cli

Пишу калькулятор на c++ с winforms вот сделал функцию нахождения корня и хотел чтоб  верхни лабель записывалось операция и число, но почему-то символ корня отображается как ? Побывал шрифт time new roman и giorgia не меняется результат

```
private: System::Void Button_sqrt_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
// Получите текущее число из result_lab
double currentNumber = System::Convert::ToDouble(this->result_lab->Text);

// Проверьте, не меньше ли число нуля
if (currentNumber < 0.0) {
    this->result_lab->Text = "Ошибка: отрицательное число";
    return;
}

// Вычислите квадратный корень
double result = sqrt(currentNumber);

// Обновите result_lab2
this->result_lab2->Text = "√(" + currentNumber.ToString() + ")";

// Обновите result_lab
this->result_lab->Text = result.ToString();
this->result_lab->ForeColor = Color::White;
```

}

Comment: Как шрифт задавали? Ну и заодно укажите, какую версию .NET используете.

Comment: #pragma execution_character_set("utf-8") вписал в код выдает место корня Взнакевролъ версию .NET свежая которая поддерживает vs 2022 4.0.16 что то такое не помню

Comment: Решил, сам IDE подсказал, поставил  L перед корнем и все заработало, убрал #pragma execution_character_set("utf-8"), конечно это не панацея, но быть может есть другие решения

Comment: Причём тут `@pragma execution_character_set`? Нужно задать шрифт _контролу_! То есть `label->Font =`.

Comment: Серьёзно? Вы даже не знаете версию, которую используете? Вон из профессии!

Comment: _поставил L_ - это вам должен был объяснить препод на первом занятии. Ну или в первой главе книги. Это ж основа!